# tabular automatic p width and right alignment

Tags: tables

I am customizing a letter and I want to place a tabular with  a multirow on the right side, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text \\
\hrule
\hfill \begin{tabular}{r p{2cm}}
    A & first line \newline second line \\
    B & text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I set the column width of the p-column to the smallest possible value?
I tried \width but it messes up the tabular.

I have seen people suggesting to use tabularx, but then I would have to specify the width of the table itself, and hfill doesn't properly align it to the right anymore. But I want both the table and the p-column to be the smallest width possible and the table aligned to the right!

EDIT: Also, A should be aligned with the first line of the multi-row.

Comment: "smallest (possible) width" = "width of longest (single) line in column"?

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would suggest the following to produce the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\hfill \begin{tabular}{r l}
    A & \makecell[l]{first line\\ second line} \\
    B & text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

By using an `l` column the width is minimal (fits the length of the longest entry) and with the usage of `makecell` you can determine where linebreaks should occure.

As pointed out by Schweinebacke in the comments, one can replace `\makecell[l]` by `\makecell[tl]` to vertically align 'A' and 'first line'.

Comment: Hm this centers A with respect to the multi-cell. I'd prefer that the A is aligned with the first line as in the MWE.

Comment: @Hyperplane: Please read the `makecell` manual. `\makecell` provides not only `l` for the optional argument but, e.g., also `t`. You can combine them to `lt` or `tl`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thank you. This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to [use `makecell`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396284/9057), you could use two table rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text \\
\hrule
\hfill \begin{tabular}{rl}
    A & first line \\
      & second line \\
    B & text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

or use a `tabular` inside a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text \\
\hrule
\hfill \begin{tabular}{rl}
    A & {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}first line \\
           second line
         \end{tabular}}\\
    B & text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Same result for both]